# I would like to create some kind of API to run a ruby program via a unique key

Tags: ruby, rest, api, server

I wrote a ruby program that runs on my local machine, and I want to turn it into a linux server API that will send back the formatted JSON file that the ruby program generates. The ruby program already works, and generates a separate JSON file on my local machine, but I would like to turn it into an API that returns the generated JSON from the program on request. The API should accept a single key, and run the program based on that key. How can I do this? What is it called that I am trying to accomplish? Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: You should read up on how to make a JSON API in ruby

Comment: @maxpleaner would that allow keys to be sent in the get request? The key is required, and each unique key generates a different json file based on the ruby program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a VERY basic example of how easy this is to do using [Sinatra](http://sinatrarb.com/) which is good for such simple type of web applications / APIs.

If we assume your current program already renders the json to a static file, for example.

#### sample.json

```
[
  {
    "item1": {
      "foo": "bar"
    },
    "item2": {
      "baz": "qux"
    }
  }
]
```

On your linux system you should have some secure random key set.  You can do that also with one liner assuming ruby is installed.

```
ruby -e 'require "SecureRandom"; puts SecureRandom.hex(32)'
```

Or in pure linux

```
date +%s | sha256sum | base64 | head -c 64 ; echo
```

Then in your server's startup scripts you'll need to make sure to export the key.

```
export API_KEY=ODAzN2EzMmI2YTc2ZDIzZjA5NzRmYmJiNjJjYmE4OGUyYjVjMDM0ZWJkZWU4NmMz
```

Then in same path as your json file, write a file called `api.rb`

```
# api.rb
require 'sinatra'

get '/api' do
  if params['key'] == ENV['API_KEY']
    return File.read 'sample.json'
  else
    status 401
  end
end
```

By default Sinatra runs on port 4567 so you'll need to expose it on your server which seems outside the scope of your Ruby question.

Depending on how and where you host this, you'll want to configure your server to run the application at startup.  For your local development you can just run this from terminal.

```
ruby app.rb
```

To see it working just visit

```
http://localhost:4567/api?key= # <<-- paste your key here.
```

Also, keep in mind, there is no security besides the key here and this will be subject to [brute force attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack), but again, that's also outside the scope of this question.

UPDATE

If you need to support multiple users with their own keys, you'll need more complex logic and likely use a database to store the user information.  API keys alone may not provide enough security if your api is serving sensitive information. So you'll probably want to add more layers of security.  You still could build this using Sinatra, but you might want to go with [Ruby on Rails to build your API](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html) instead.

Comment: Would this cause any issues if multiple people used the program at once? The JSON file generated by the program is different for each request, so my main concern would be that if multiple people are reading from the same JSON file, it wouldn’t return the right JSON for one of the users.

Comment: Do you have a limited number of users?  How many?  Will that list need to grow over time?  This would surely need to change to support that.  How do you go about distributing the keys?  It sounds like you need a more fully structured web app api backed with database to store  user informations, keys etc.  For that you probably want to lean towards [Ruby on Rails start reading here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html)

Comment: The way the ruby program works is it takes two hashed queries (username and password), and generates a JSON file after doing something with the username & password. Therefore, the JSON file will be completely different, based on the username and password. The amount of users at one time would most likely never surpass 36, but there should be room for potential growth. My question is, how could I use these queries to interact with the ruby program and send back the JSON generated from it?

Comment: @Alien you should combine your current ruby program into your API application.  But I have no idea what that program looks like.  I've given you as much help as I can on this question.  Now you need to read up on both Sinatra and Rails and decide which one is best for your use case.  Then go ahead and build your fully working API as a single ruby application.